# How can I simplify this function?

Tags: python

Is there any way to simplify this function?  Specifically, I'd like to rewrite it with fewer lines of indentation.

```
# split string (first argument) at location of separators (second argument, should be a string)
def split_string(text, separators):
    text = ' ' + text + ' '
    words = []
    word = ""
    for char in text:
        if char not in separators:
            word += char
        else:
            if word:
                words.append(word)
            word = ""
    if not words:
        words.append(text)
    return words
```

Comment: And what is this function doing?

Comment: split string (first argument) at location of separators (second argument, should be a string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code seems to produce

```
>>> split_string("foo.,.bar", ".,")
[' foo']
```

but your comment says

```
split_string("foo.,.bar", ".,") will return ["foo", "bar"]
```

Assuming the comment is what's intended, then I'd use `itertools.groupby` (I hate using regexes):

```
from itertools import groupby

def splitter(text, separators):
    grouped = groupby(text, lambda c: c in separators)
    return [''.join(g) for k,g in grouped if not k]
```

which gives

```
>>> splitter("foo.,.bar", ".,")
['foo', 'bar']
```

`groupby` returns an iterator over consecutive terms grouped by some function -- in this case, `lambda c: c in separators` -- of the terms.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to itertools!  This works very well!

Answer (score 6):

Try using [re.split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), for example:

```
re.split('[%s]' % (separators),string)
```

The `[]` creates a regular expression character class to split on.

Comment: Great solution except that you should escape the characters in separators just in case they are reqex qualifiers: `re.split('[%s]' % '\\'.join(separators), text)`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method. Taken from the official documentation:

> #### str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])
>
> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string.
> If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done (thus, the list will have
> at most maxsplit+1 elements). If maxsplit is not specified or -1, then there is no
> limit on the number of splits (all possible splits are made).
>
> If sep is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and are deemed
> to delimit empty strings (for example, '1,,2'.split(',') returns ['1', '', '2']).
> The sep argument may consist of multiple characters (for example,
> '1<>2<>3'.split('<>') returns ['1', '2', '3']). Splitting an empty string with a
> specified separator returns [''].
>
> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied:
> runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result
> will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or
> trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting
> of just whitespace with a None separator returns [].
>
> For example, ' 1  2   3  '.split() returns ['1', '2', '3'], and
> '  1  2   3  '.split(None, 1) returns ['1', '2   3  '].

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing with str.split()?  From my understanding, str.split(". ,") will split a string at every instance that ". ," occur as consecutive characters.  This function will split the string any time any one of those chars occurs.  ie: split_string("foo.,.bar", ".,") will return ["foo", "bar"], whereas ("foo.,.bar").split(".,") will return ["foo", ".bar"]

Comment: So, what you meant is to implement a `split(sep_list)` where `sep_list` is a list of possible separators ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that will not work for what I'm trying to do.  See first comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
myString = "Some-text-here"
splitWords = myString.split("-")
```

The above code will return a List of with the words separated. I used "-" as the delimiter, you may assign any delimiter you like. Default is the "space" delimiter like this:

```
myString = "Some text here"
splitWords = myString.split()
```